# Android System Apps Code Coverage

Tags: android, android-source

I have downloaded **[AOSP](https://source.android.com/)**, for every system app there are local unit tests provided.

*For those tests how to get code coverage?*

Comment: what you mean by code coverage ? explain more.

Comment: We can run unit test cases with coverage in android studio to find out how many lines of code is covered. it will be achieved by Emma or jacoco. In a similar way I need to run test cases with coverage from terminal using commands.

Comment: @Naveen did you get an answer to this?